# Is "dandy" considered offensive?

Tags: word-usage, offensive-language

Is calling someone a dandy considered offensive or has a negative meaning nowadays?

English is not my native language, so I wanted to clarify this for me. I understand the meaning of the word, but I was surprised, when I was told that calling someone a dandy is considered quite offensive in South America. It's interpreted as "rich kid" and has a negative meaning. So I was wondering if it's the same for English speaking countries.

Comment: Google the word, tell us what definition you get, and then tell us if you think it has a negative meaning.

Comment: @JohnClifford English is not my native language, so I wanted to clarify this for me. I understand the meaning of the word, but I was surprised, when I was told that calling someone a dandy is considered quite offensive in South America. It's interpreted as "rich kid" and has a negative meaning. So I was wondering if it's the same for English speaking countries.

Comment: It is. One of dandy's meanings is "a man who is unduly concerned with looking stylish and fashionable" and has as synonyms such words as "fop" and "coxcomb" all of which have a negative connotation of vanity.

Comment: Your comments about South America, rich kids, negative meanings, and why you were wondering what you were wondering probably ought to be edited into your question, rather than buried down here in the comments. More context and background generally leads to a more dandy question (no insult intended).

Comment: It might be worth noting that the long-established but somewhat "quaint" usage [*fine and dandy*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fine+and+dandy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfine%20and%20dandy%3B%2Cc0) (which is experiencing something of a comeback in recent decades) very often appears in contexts such as *That's all fine and dandy, **but**...*. Where I'd say the word becomes somewhat more "negative by association" - but maybe not, since the same obviously *doesn't* happen with ***fine***.

Comment: In America and the UK, these days, it's a very archaic term.  I think that if you used it now you'd more likely confuse someone than insult them.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Are you insulting their intelligence? ;)

Comment: @Max Williams: Yes, but I think "archaic" is putting it a bit strong - "dated" would be better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers perhaps, is there a difference between dated and archaic though?  I thought they were pretty much synonymous.  Although, a quick google reveals that you could think of "dated" as meaning "only said by old people" whereas archaic is more like "hardly said by anybody, any more".  In that case, you're probably right.

Comment: Still though, if someone said to me, "Well, aren't you quite the dandy", i'd probably be flattered (if i was dressed smartly), or insulted if i wasn't dressed smartly, assuming they were being sarcastic.  But, you know, i'm not a retired colonel from Tennessee or something.

Comment: You mention English and South America. Are you talking about how they use this word in Guyana? Otherwise, are you talking about Spanish or Brazilian Portuguese? And which country for Spanish? And those are all entirely different languages from English so the connotations may be entirely different. Also, there's the primary denotative meaning, and then the pragmatic implications. 'Small' is a derogatory term for football players, but not for transistors.

Comment: @Max Williams: I'm sure outfits like OED make a fairly clear distinction between, say, "obsolete" and "archaic" (and "dated", if they use that in their definitions). But to me they're definitely on a continuum, with considerable overlap. As a rule of thumb I'd say "archaic" means *still "known", but no longer used "naturally"* - and I think my father is quite capable of using ***dandy*** without thinking of it as an "antiquated" usage. But he's 95, and the bottom line is the usage will definitely be archaic when all people who currently still use it naturally are dead.

Comment: @Mitch I'm living in Colombia, and my friends here use the word *dandi* (o *gomelo*), referring to a pretentious person, who talks with excessive pride about his social position, wears expensive clothes (not always with a good taste).

Comment: @vero4ka: But that is not really what the word means in English.  Or meant: as others have said, it's rather dated (in the sense of describing someone as a 'dandy'), having fallen out of common use probably around the 1930s.

Comment: @vero4ka I'm sure, since one language borrowed it from another, that they are similar in meaning and usage, but it's still a different language and culture so equating the two (uses of the words in the two languages) cannot be assumed. 'Dandy', 'fop' , 'metrosexual', 'clothes horse' are all in the same area and are not offensive at all (they are not taboo words or vulgar or shaming. One could use them to praise their fashion sense or to imply that they are vain. It does not mean 'rich kid' at all in English.

Comment: I just remembered that the now-ubiquitous "dude" was originally a synonym for "dandy", both of them being american west/cowboy words for well dressed city gentlemen.  They carry an implied insult that the subject wouldn't be able to cope with the tough country life, away from their soft city beds etc.  A "dude ranch" was a ranch where city gents would go and "play cowboy", like in the film City Slickers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's offensive; you wouldn't use the term to insult someone. But you would use it as a term of ridicule.

Comment: So ridiculing someone need not be considered offensive?

Comment: @Edwin "You're no Jack Kennedy" is ridiculing, but is not offensive. That's not what offensive means.

Comment: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ridicule): **ridicule**: 'the subjection of someone or something to contemptuous and dismissive language or behaviour.' synonyms:  mockery, derision, ... scorn, scoffing, contempt, jeering, sneering, ... sarcasm. // [Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ridicule): **ridicule** – the act of deriding or treating with contempt
_derision_:
offense, offensive activity, discourtesy, offence – a lack of politeness; a failure to show regard for others; wounding the feelings or others // I'd suggest 'to gently poke fun at ...'.